# How can I take money from a customer's account?

Tags: anchor

The documentation on "Become an anchor>Architecture" says the first option is "Maintain a Stellar account for each customer. When a customer deposits money with your institution, you should pay an equivalent amount of your custom asset into the customer’s Stellar account from your base account. When a customer needs to obtain physical currency from you, deduct the equivalent amount of your custom asset from their Stellar account."

I'm baffled as to how I can take money from a customer's account. Are the asset anchors able to arbitrarily DB any stellar account holding that asset? if not, what does the last sentence mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case that you're referring to, the anchor is expected to (as the doc says) "maintain a Stellar account for each customer", i.e. a managed wallet where the anchor controls the private keys. (This is standard practice for crypto exchanges).

Given that the anchor controls the account's private keys, they are free to debit the user's managed Stellar account when they request to redeem the Asset.

Comment: That's how I read it. The anchor creates and owns an account per customer. It's not the customer's account to control directly.

Comment: OK, I see. It is confusing because most anchors are going to let a user use his own account which isn't even listed as an option! So this section is written for anchors who need to control distribution of their asset using a private key per account or a single account. I think it would be a LOT less confusing if they listed the most common case first (user controlled). What do you think?